# On Artinian rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, artin-ring

Let $R$ be a ring, and for every $R$-module $M$, suppose that we have the following condition:

**If $M$ is cogenerated by any finitely generated $R$-module $N$, then $M$ embeds in a finite direct sum of copies of $N$.**

Does this assumption imply that $R$ is right Artinian?

Comment: Assuming that "$M$ is cogenerated by $N$" means that $M$ embeds in a direct product of copies of $N$, then if $M$ is the direct product of a large family of copies of $N$, then it's cogenerated by $N$ but is too large to embed in a finite direct sum of copies of $N$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But this assumption can be happen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of the above question. The answer is this: Under this assumption R does not need to be right Artinian. Thank you.